# How to create a list of Object by from 2 different list of objects based on a matching criteria in java 8

Tags: java, loops, java-8, nested, java-stream

How to write the below piece code using java 8 streams.

We have one list containing book details of last year and another list of book details of current year. We need to consolidate two list to get the final details of book. The older edition of book in current year list needs to be compared with the last year list to determine the price of those books. the match crietria between both list is the book id. And we are not suppose to modify the BookDetailsLastYear list  and BookDetailsCurrentYear List.

```
public List<Books> determineLatestBookDetails(List<BookDetailsLastYear> lastYearDetails, List<BookDetailsCurrentYear> currentYearDetails) {

    List<Books> booklist = new ArrayList<>();
    for(BookDetailsLastYear bdly: lastYearDetails) {
        if(bdly.getId() > 15) {
            for(BookDetailsCurrentYear bdcy: currentYearDetails) {
                if(!bdcy.getEdition().equals("current")) {
                    if(bdly.getId() == bdcy.getId()) {
                        Books book = new Books();
                        book.setId(bdly.getId());

                        if(bdly.getPrice() >= bdcy.getPrice()) {
                            book.setPrice(bdly.getPrice());
                        } else {
                            book.setPrice(bdcy.getPrice());
                        }
                        booklist.add(book);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   return booklist;
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You shouldn't name a class in the plural unless an instance represents more than one object.

Comment: @shmosel this is a common thing for non-native English speakers. On my project people write similar like simular, cross-sell, like crosssale, variation-axis like variation-axes, and you can't do anything about that...

Comment: @Wow Besides for informing people you mean.

Comment: @Naresh, I think your code logic is quite flawed, because you need to check if current year's books have "current" in the edition field.

Comment: @shmosel I did inform, no one cares.

Comment: @shmosel - Thanks for your review. It helps to improve my coding standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't vouch for the correctness of your code because you haven't included much context, but this should be an accurate equivalent:

```
return lastYearDetails.stream()
        .filter(bdly -> bdly.getId() > 15)
        .flatMap(bdly -> currentYearDetails.stream()
                .filter(bdcy -> !bdcy.getEdition().equals("current"))
                .filter(bdcy -> bdcy.getId() == bdly.getId())
                .map(bdcy -> {
                    Books book = new Books();
                    book.setId(bdly.getId());
                    book.setPrice(Math.max(bdly.getPrice(), bdcy.getPrice()));
                    return book;
                }))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Wow Thanks for the quick response and the code worked fine. The use case given here was not my actual use case, it is similar to the one which i'm working on. So really didn't think much on the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<Books> books = lastYearDetails.stream()
    .filter(bdly -> bdly.getId() > 15)
    .map(bdly -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
        bdly,
        currentYearDetails.stream()
            .filter(bdcy -> !bdcy.getEdition().equals("current"))
            .filter(bdcy -> bdcy.getId() == bdly.getId())
            .findFirst()
    ))
    .filter(pair -> pair.getValue().isPresent())
    .map(pair -> {
            Books book = new Books();
            book.setId(pair.getKey().getId());
            book.setPrice(Math.max(pair.getKey().getPrice(), pair.getValue().getPrice()));
            return book;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```